# Django media file page not found

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-staticfiles, django-media

So, I'm trying to follow [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) about the static files and media files

I have a clean Django installation and I want to add the media folder. What I've done? I've changed the `urls.py` inside the project (not the app) and the `settings.py` as below

### settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But I got the

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Using the URLconf defined in
> web_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ ^media/(?P.*)$ The empty path didn’t match any of these.

I've also tried adding the `'django.template.context_processors.media'` into `TEMPLATES` and using os as below

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

but nothing changes

What it could be?

Comment: did you create an **app**  in your project

Comment: @monim yes, and I'm able to create database objects surfing to /admin

Comment: that's not an error  it just the how django works check my answer

Comment: You don't have URL for a home page. All you got is `admin` and `media`, but you're trying to open `/` and django is clearly saying `The empty path didn’t match any of these.` Define `path('')` for home page or open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` - the only path your app can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting this error is the expected behavior because  when you add a path to `urlpatterns` in **urls.py** in your example `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` you'll no more get access to  **`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`** (it just renders a  “Congratulations!” page, with a rocket taking off. It worked! ) unless you specify a view to this empty path (which you didn't)

In your case, there is no URL leading to  ***`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`*** . the only paths you get access to are :

**1-**  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` for the admin page

**2 -** `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/(?P<path>.*)$`  to access you media files
for example, if you have an image **img.png**  in **media folder** you can access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/img.png` and view your image

Answer (score 1):

The `static` function is only intended to serve static files during development and is not suitable for serving user-uploaded media files.

Try to make a condition check that whether `DEBUG=True` or not so:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```